# Is it possible to copy paste text from clipboard to IText with styles of the copied text

Tags: fabricjs

I use IText with styles: { }.

Is there a way to copy paste the text from clipboard to IText on canvas
so that IText keeps the styles of the copied original text (font color, bold, underline)?

```
function createText(){
    var text = new fabric.IText('some text', {
        styles: { }
    });

    return text;
}

function createCanvas(id){
    canvas=new fabric.Canvas(id);
    canvas.hoverCursor="default";

    someText=createText();
    canvas.add(someText);

    return canvas;
}
```

Comment: By default, it won't. You need to add that style property in the styles object.

Comment: Maybe we can create some auxiliary function that gets styles of the copied text and sets it to fabric styles before pasting to canvas?